# JPA Specification with @ManyToMany property

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 entities which are related with @ManyToMany relation:

```
public class EntityA {

@Id
private Long id;
.
.
.
@ManyToMany(fetch = fetchType.EAGER)
private List<EntityB> listOfB;

}
```

I want to create JPA specification that will query IN clause by id of EntityB.
I have tried

```
  private static Specification<EntityA> listOfB(String path, List<Long> idsOfB) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            //path is passed as "listOfB"
            return root.get(path).in(idsOfB);
        };
    }
```

but I get **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."**

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing the SQL that is failing so I can only guess what goes wrong. One possible issue is that the list of ids is empty.

Since you are writing that you are passing `listOfB`, the real problem is that you are comparing entities with a list of longs, which doesn't work.

You either need to use reference objects i.e. proxies, by using `idsOfB.stream().map(id -> em.getReference(EntityB.class, id)).collect(toList())` or you join the `listOfB`.

I think what you really want though, is to use an EXISTS predicate. Something like this:

```
private static Specification<EntityA> listOfB(String path, List<Long> idsOfB) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Subquery<Integer> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<EntityA> root = subquery.correlate(root);
        subquery.where(root.join(path).get("id").in(idsOfB));
        subquery.select(cb.literal(1L));
        return cb.exists(subquery);
    };
}
```